# pydev cannot run unittest (it works in spyder)

Tags: python, pydev, python-unittest

This is not extremely important since I can make it work in `spyder`, but I like `pydev` quite a lot (I'm very used to eclipse) and it is just annoying, I've spent some time on it already and I'd like to fix it.

I've got this `unittest` (actually it belongs to `nltk`) and I cannot make it work in `pydev`. Things that I've tried:

- Run it in `spyder` => it works fine
- Updated `pydev` and `eclipse` (though I'm not yet in eclipse Mars released last week; my versions are, for eclipse 4.5.0.20150603-1639 and for pydev 4.1.0.2015052700003)
- I can run other unit tests perfectly with pydev, with breakpoints and everything, provided they are in projects different to `nltk`
- Read quite a few SO questions, but didn't find anything that helped much
- I've also tried to copy parts of the content of the test to one of my projects and it works well -which probably means there's something silly I'm doing, but I don't get it. Must be something about the combination of my environment with the fact of running the test from the `nltk` structure
- Get the same behavior in python 2.7 and 3.4

The error that I get is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lorenzorubio/tools/pydev-mars/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.1.0.201505270003/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pydevd_breakpoints import * #@UnusedWildImport
  File "/Users/lorenzorubio/tools/pydev-mars/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.1.0.201505270003/pysrc/pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 71, in patched_import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lorenzorubio/tools/pydev-mars/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.1.0.201505270003/pysrc/pydevd_breakpoints.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pydevd_comm import GetGlobalDebugger
  File "/Users/lorenzorubio/tools/pydev-mars/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.1.0.201505270003/pysrc/pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 71, in patched_import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lorenzorubio/tools/pydev-mars/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.1.0.201505270003/pysrc/pydevd_comm.py", line 79, in <module>
    import _pydev_completer
  File "/Users/lorenzorubio/tools/pydev-mars/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.1.0.201505270003/pysrc/pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 71, in patched_import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lorenzorubio/tools/pydev-mars/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.1.0.201505270003/pysrc/_pydev_completer.py", line 21, in <module>
    import _pydev_imports_tipper
  File "/Users/lorenzorubio/tools/pydev-mars/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.1.0.201505270003/pysrc/pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 71, in patched_import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lorenzorubio/tools/pydev-mars/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.1.0.201505270003/pysrc/_pydev_imports_tipper.py", line 2, in <module>
    import inspect
  File "/Users/lorenzorubio/tools/pydev-mars/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.1.0.201505270003/pysrc/pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 71, in patched_import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lorenzorubio/tools/anaconda/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 39, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/Users/lorenzorubio/tools/pydev-mars/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.1.0.201505270003/pysrc/pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 71, in patched_import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lorenzorubio/git/nltk/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from nltk.data              import load
  File "/Users/lorenzorubio/tools/pydev-mars/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.1.0.201505270003/pysrc/pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 71, in patched_import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lorenzorubio/git/nltk/nltk/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
    from nltk.decorators import decorator, memoize
  File "/Users/lorenzorubio/tools/pydev-mars/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.1.0.201505270003/pysrc/pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 71, in patched_import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lorenzorubio/git/nltk/nltk/decorators.py", line 183, in <module>
    @decorator
  File "/Users/lorenzorubio/git/nltk/nltk/decorators.py", line 161, in decorator
    if inspect.isclass(caller):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'isclass'
```

I was hoping that somebody maybe could give me a hint about what is happening.

The test is in [this github link](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/twitter/nltk/test/unit/test_json2csv_corpus.py). (In order to run it you should download `nltk` in the twitter branch, though it should be merged to the main branch soon, but anyway, I don't expect anybody to actually run it, it is already enough to get one person annoyed with this).

I'm using `anaconda` for dealing with the `python` installation, and of course I add in the PYTHONPATH the path of the branch I'm using for `nltk`.

Thank you so much for your reading and maybe your pointers.

**EDIT**: Thanks @That1Guy for your comment!

It is indeed a conflict in naming, not in `inspect` but in `tokenize`. There is a `tokenize` in python that conflicts with the `tokenize` in `nltk`. I did try to change in `.../anaconda/lib/python2.7/inspect.py` and instead of

```
import tokenize
```

I edit to

```
from tokenize import tokenize
```

and it works!

(`nltk` tokenize would be `import nltk.tokenize`)

Still, it is not clean at all to modify a system file... is there a better solution? And why this happens only in `pydev`?

Thanks again.

Comment: My guess is it's a naming conflict somewhere. `inspect` must be two different things, but the pydev `import inspect` happens after the original definition of `inspect`.

Comment: Indeed, it is related to the `inspect`! I've updated the question. Thanks!